# Not getting event's reminder alert on iOS device

Tags: ios, popup, google-calendar-api, reminders

As per Google Calendar API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders)

> The delivery methods offered by Google Calendar are: Pop-up. These are
>   supported on mobile platforms and on web clients.

Reminder alert popups are supported on mobile platforms, but it's not showing any alert popup (reminder) when any new event is created or events are fetched.

I'm using Google Calendar API v3 for iOS [api](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios)
How to add support for reminder for type popup inside my app?

Following is the code I'm using but it does not show reminder alert popup

```
- (void)createEvent
{
    NSDate *date = [TDUtils dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitMinute value:10 toDate:[NSDate date]];
    GTLDateTime *startTime = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:date timeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    GTLCalendarEventDateTime *start = [[GTLCalendarEventDateTime alloc] init];
    [start setDateTime:startTime];
    
    NSDate *edate = [TDUtils dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitHour value:1 toDate:date];
    GTLDateTime *endTime = [GTLDateTime dateTimeWithDate:edate timeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    GTLCalendarEventDateTime *end = [[GTLCalendarEventDateTime alloc] init];
    [end setDateTime:endTime];
    
    GTLCalendarEventReminder *reminder = [[GTLCalendarEventReminder alloc] init];
    [reminder setMethod:@"popup"];
    [reminder setMinutes:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
    
    GTLCalendarEventReminders *reminders = [[GTLCalendarEventReminders alloc] init];
    [reminders setUseDefault:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    [reminders setOverrides:@[reminder]];
    
    GTLCalendarEvent *event = [[GTLCalendarEvent alloc] init];
    [event setSummary:@"test reminder"];
    [event setLocation:@"New delhi"];
    [event setDescriptionProperty:@"event description"];
    [event setStart:start];
    [event setEnd:end];
    [event setReminders:reminders];
    
    GTLQueryCalendar *query = [GTLQueryCalendar queryForEventsInsertWithObject:event calendarId:self.calendarID];
    
    [self.service executeQuery:query
             completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLCalendarEvent* object, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error create event: %@(%ld)", error.localizedDescription, (long)error.code);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"success: %@", object.JSONString);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: From the Reminder and Notification you've mentioned, you need to include the reminders [Events resource properties](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#reminders.overrides):

"reminders": {
  "useDefault": "useDefault",
  # Overrides can be set if and only if useDefault is false.
  "overrides": [
      {
        "method": "reminderMethod",
        "minutes": "reminderMinutes"
      },
      # ...
  ]
}

Comment: Thanks @noogui! I have included reminders properties in my code, as you can see in my code above. What I'm expecting is that Google Calendar API will automatically handle and show reminder alert/notification in my iOS device if reminder method is set as "popup". It is working fine in case reminder method is set as "email".

Comment: The calendar client is the thing showing the pop up, not the API. So unless the iOS user has the account setup on the device (for example via the Google calendar app or the native iOS calendar app) there won't be any pop ups.